# dual monitor parent child window issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two monitors. When my application runs, the parent is displayed on the first monitor. When I move the parent window to the second monitor and click a button (diaplay a xaml window for loading), this child window stays on the first monitor. Is there a way to make the child window stay with the parent window no matter where the parent window is located?

please note: parent is winform ... child is xaml.

loading xaml (child)

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Loading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    WindowStyle="None" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Background="Gray">

    <Grid>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="Loading ..." />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Parent

```
    private void btnShowLoading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Loading load = new Loading();

    double top = this.Top;
    double left = this.Left;

    load.Top = top;
    load.Left = left;

    load.Show();
}
```

Comment: What kind of type Loading is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`childWindow.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;`

UPDATE 1:

Get your parent window's location and set it to child window.
If you think your parent window's state changes, you may use this to get actual Top and Left:

```
var leftField = typeof(Window).GetField("_actualLeft", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var topField = typeof(Window).GetField("_actualTop", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

double left = (double)leftField.GetValue(parentWindow);

double top = (double)topField.GetValue(parentWindow);
```

source: [Window ActualTop, ActualLeft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600874/window-actualtop-actualleft)

UPDATE 2:
First of all you had to tell that the `parentWindow` is `WinForms`. 
In this case you can get parentWindow's `Top` and `Left` like this:

```
double top = this.Top;
double left = this.Left;
```

Then pass the top and left of the `parentWindow` to the `childWindow`. When `childWindow` loaded it should set `top` and `left`.

Comment: Then try getting parentWindow's location and set it to childWindow.

Comment: I've tried the code you've provided and assigned it to the child's Left/Top and yet still the same result.

Comment: did you debug it? did it return the correct left and top of the parent window?

Comment: I am sure you are not passing the left and top to child Window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26668/discussion-between-dilshod-and-user1884032)

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you need to manually set the owner window - it is not done automatically.  From [Window.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx):

> A window that is opened by calling Show does not automatically have a
>   relationship with the window that opened it; specifically, the opened
>   window does not know which window opened it. This relationship can be
>   established using the Owner property and managed using the
>   OwnedWindows property.

Since your Loading window has no owner, it will be centered on your primary monitor.  Use the code below:

```
private void btnShowLoading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Loading load = new Loading();
    load.Owner = this;
    load.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner; 
    load.Show();
}
```

Comment: my parent window is a winform control while the child is a xaml(window) control. I dont know how to set the owner of the child window. When I set the owner to the parent window, i get error of "Cannot implicitly convert type system.windows.forms.form to system.windows.window.

Comment: Are you hosting the winform control in a `WindowsFormsHost`?  If so you would have to get a reference to it.  If not how are you combining WinForms and WPF?

Comment: no, i have a winform which gets access to the xaml by namespace.